# Issue with handling cell re-iteration in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a very interesting case in which I have two `UITableViews`.  The primary `TableView` is a `UITableViewController`.  Each cell is made up of three parts.  The `Header` which display a title, the `Body` which acts as an accordion when you select your `cell`, and finally a `UITableView` that uses a custom `Cell Identifier` but uses the same delegate as the `UITableViewController` or `parent`.

Now the problem I am having is, when the user scrolls around, all the titles get jumbled up for the `parent uitableview` and as well as the `child uitableview` and I know it has to do with my `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

[image: jumbled text]

Where the word `developer` is, that is the parent `tableview`.  The jumbled text `that is a sub uitableview`.  I'm looking for some guidance on the best possible solution to solve this problem.  Here is what I am doing:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            // #  Adjust profile picture
        //cell.headerView.profileImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)
        cell.headerView.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "avatar-ph.jpg")
        cell.headerView.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 
             cell.headerView.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2

        cell.headerView.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true

         ... do stuff
            cell.detailView.innertableView.dataSource = self

            // This is needed for dequeueing to succeed:
            cell.detailView.innertableView.registerClass(SingleOrderTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SingleOrderTableViewCell");

            cell.detailView.innertableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
// [B] INNER TABLE VIEW
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SingleOrderTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleOrderTableViewCell


            // #  Setup our data to display
        // ## Title
        cell.title = UITextField (frame:CGRectMake(75, 5, 300, 20));
        cell.title.font = UIFont(name: "System Light", size: 10);
        cell.title.text = drinkName;

        cell.title.textColor = UIColor(netHex:0x362C6B);
        // ## qty
        cell.qty = UITextField (frame:CGRectMake(75, 22.5, 300, 20));
        cell.qty.font = UIFont(name: "System Light", size: 10);
        cell.qty.text = "Qty: " + qty;
        cell.qty.textColor = UIColor.grayColor();


        // #  Add to subframe
        cell.addSubview(cell.title);
        cell.addSubview(cell.qty);
           return cell
        }
}
```

The code above show cases how I handle the distinguishing of the two `tableviews` and set the corresponding cells to their correct `tableview`.

Now another thing to note that the information that is populated here is based off an object returned from the server.  So my thought was, it is working correctly; but the `indexPath.row` is off from the actual associated `cell`.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: @Rob Yes I am doing `cell.addsubview`, etc... to add the `uitextfields` to the screen.

Comment: @Rob thanks, please check update.

Comment: @rob could you provide any sample code for that suggestion?  I definitely agree though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You are dequeueing cells using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(indexPath:)`, but you are adding subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Unfortunately that means that when a cell is re-used, you're adding a new label each time.

   If you're going to use this approach of programmatically created cells, you should move the adding of the subviews into the `UITableViewCell` subclasses' `init` or `awakeFromNIB` methods. Those methods are called only once, and not called again when the cell is reused for another row in the table.
2. I might suggesting simplifying this further, cutting the Gordian knot, and not programmatically creating cells at all. Instead, you can add prototype cells right in your storyboard, and then you don't have to call `addSubview` yourself at all. The process for using cell prototypes is as follows:

   - Create blank `UITableViewCell` subclass.
   - Add cell prototype to your tableview cell. You do this by dragging a "Table View Cell" from the Interface Builder Object Library onto your table view. (Generally, it gives you a cell prototype and you don't have to do this, though.)
   - Set the base class for the cell prototype to be your `UITableViewCell` subclass on the "Identity Inspector" panel in Interface Builder. Also give that prototype cell a unique storyboard identifier on the "Attributes Inspector" panel.
   - Drag whatever controls you want on this cell in Interface Builder at design time, rather than programmatically at run time.
   - Add `IBOutlet` references for the controls you added in Interface Builder to your cell into your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

   If you have two different types of cells, repeat this process for each.
3. Unrelated to your original question, rather than doing a tableview within a tableview, I'd suggest creating a single tableview with two cell prototypes, one for the the header cell and then one for the detail cell.

   Then you can create a separate "section" in your table view for each collapsable group of cells. The `numberOfRowsInSection` will then determine how many rows there are on the basis of whether the group is collapsed or not. If it's collapsed, just return `1` for the header cell. If it's not collapsed, return `1` plus the number of detail rows in that section.

   So, when you want to hide the rows, update some flag in your model to reflect that the section is collapsed and then call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` with the appropriate animation to hide the rows. Or when you want to show the rows, again, update model and then call `addRowsAtIndexPaths`.

   For example, consider the following:

   ```
   struct Comedian {
       let name: String
   }

   struct Troupe {
       let name: String
       let items: [Comedian]
       var collapsed = false
   }

   class ViewController: UITableViewController {

       var comedyTroupes = [
           Troupe(name: "The Three Stooges", collapsed: true, items: [
               Comedian(name: "Mo"),
               Comedian(name: "Larry"),
               Comedian(name: "Curly")]
           ),
           Troupe(name: "The Marx Brothers", collapsed: true, items: [
               Comedian(name: "Chico"),
               Comedian(name: "Harpo"),
               Comedian(name: "Groucho"),
               Comedian(name: "Gummo"),
               Comedian(name: "Zeppo")]
           ),
           Troupe(name: "The Smothers Brothers", collapsed: true, items: [
               Comedian(name: "Richard"),
               Comedian(name: "Thomas")]
           ),
           Troupe(name: "Laurel and Hardy", collapsed: true, items: [
               Comedian(name: "Laurel"),
               Comedian(name: "Hardy")]
           ),
           Troupe(name: "Abbott and Costello", collapsed: true, items: [
               Comedian(name: "Abbott"),
               Comedian(name: "Costello")]
           ),
       ]

       override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
           return comedyTroupes.count
       }

       // if the section is collapsed, we only have the header cell; otherwise we have header cell and detail cells

       override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return comedyTroupes[section].collapsed ? 1 : comedyTroupes[section].items.count + 1
       }

       // row 0 will be the name of the comedy troupe; the rest of the rows will be the names of the comedians

       override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           if indexPath.row == 0 {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
               cell.comedyTroupeLabel.text = comedyTroupes[indexPath.section].name
               return cell
           } else {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DetailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailCell
               cell.comedianNameLabel.text = comedyTroupes[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row - 1].name
               return cell
           }
       }

       // if we select header row, update model and then either call
       // `addRowsAtIndexPaths or `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` as appropriate.

       override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           if indexPath.row == 0 {
               let collapsed = !comedyTroupes[indexPath.section].collapsed
               comedyTroupes[indexPath.section].collapsed = collapsed
               let indexPaths = Array(1 ... comedyTroupes[indexPath.section].items.count).map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: indexPath.section) }
               if collapsed {
                   tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Middle)
               } else {
                   tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Middle)
               }
           } else {
               // do whatever you want if user selects one of the detail cells
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   That yields:

   [image]

   Now, I happen to be collapsing and expanding the detail rows whenever the header row is selected, but you could use whatever UI you want (e.g., you could add some button on the header row cell to twizzle the detail rows open and closed). Also, if you don't like this "extra header row" model, you can also use proper section header views (but then you have to jump through hoops to add header view to your table view, capture clicks on it, etc.). I think this header cell and detail cell approach is easiest, albeit not as intuitive. But, regardless, I hope this illustrates the idea that you don't need tableviews within tableviews.

Comment: Thanks so much for this awesome response Rob.  Here is my current solution after taking your advice.  I am going to have the single `tableviewcontroller` where each `cell` associates with a `header` and `body`.  Within the `body` instead of using another `uitableview` I am just going to have a `uiview` and populate `uilabels`.  Let me know what you think about that?

Comment: Also question about what you wrote, when you call a `reloaddata()` on the table, wouldn't there be an issue with overlap?

Comment: That certainly use the multiple label approach, too, though it seems like it's extra work to add the labels, add all of the necessary constraints, etc. Also, I assumed you might want to have the ability to click on then: By having all of the details be their own rows in the table, you have that added flexibility. Plus you get a variety of different animations for showing/hiding rows. And if you're going to just add a bunch of labels, you might use a stack view (if targeting iOS 9 and later).

Comment: Regarding `reloadData`, I generally wouldn't do that, but rather just `reload` the relevant cells or section. If you reload the whole table, it scrolls back to the top (and you don't get the nice animation showing the user what changed). Sure, if the table view is being completely reloaded from network resource, call `reloadData`, but not for every collapse/expansion of a section. But in answer to your question, no, you don't get any overlap or anything like that.

Comment: So @Rob it sounds like your more in favor with the multi interlaced `tableview`?  So as of right now I am just displaying data to the left.  I have buttons on the right that are linked to `selectors`.  So all I need right now is to display data.  I was originally using the `uitableview ` because it had the scroll already in place, etc...

Comment: I also am already using an Accordion like collapse with extends each `uitableviewcell`.  I like your method, very straight to the point and simple.

Comment: Sounds fine. Do whatever makes sense for your desired UX. I was just showing one (common) example of collapsing and expanding all within a single tableview.

Comment: It was an great anwser and I learned something new.  Thank you so much!